# Confused about the 'cpu_set_t' structure definition in sched.h

Tags: c, linux

From what I have read online and seen in `struct.h` , `cpu_set_t` is a struct that contains a bit mask, where each bit represents a CPU that can be used by the thread/process.

This is how it is defined:

```
typedef struct
{ __CPU_BITTYPE  __bits[ CPU_SETSIZE / __CPU_BITS ];
} cpu_set_t
```

`__CPU_BITTYPE` is an `unsigned long int`.

Doesn't the above `cpu_set_t` definition mean that the struct contains an array called `__bits` of size `CPU_SETSIZE / __CPU_BITS`? What am I missing here? How is it interpreted as a bit field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's an array. This is to allow for the possibility that there may be more CPUs than the number of bits in an integer.

`CPU_SETSIZE` is the total number of CPUs in a CPU set, and `__CPU_BITS` is the number of bits used in each integer to hold the bit mask. To access the bit for a particular CPU, you divide the CPU number by `__CPU_BITS` to get the array index, and use the modulus as a left shift to get to that bit in the integer. There's almost certainly a macro that performs this operation.

This is generally how bit arrays are implemented in C when you can't limit the number of elements to the size in bits of an integer type.

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense! Yep, you're right there are macros that do this (namely CPU_SET, CPU_ZERO etc). I was confused about their operation too, because I didn't understand the basic structure of cpu_set_t.